# Loop and If statement to check and load packages

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, require, install.packages

Why wont require take a vector of packages? Also is there a way to split pkg for both install.package and BiocManager? Thus, if packages fails to install with install.package, check with BiocManager?

Error:
[1] "stringr"
Loading required package: i
Error in print.default("trying to install", i) :
invalid printing digits -2147483648
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
there is no package called ‘i’
2: In print.default("trying to install", i) : NAs introduced by coercion

```
pkg <- c("stringr", "openxlsx")

for (i in pkg){
    print(i)
    if(require(i)){
       print(i, "is loaded correctly")
    } else{
       print("trying to install", i)
       install.packages(i)
       if(require(i)){
          print(i, "installed and loaded")
       } else{
          stop("could not install", i)
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at `?try()` or `?tryCatch()` for trying to do something, then doing something else if it fails. You could also use `available.packages()` to check if the package is in a repository before trying to install it.

Comment: As to "*Why wont require take a vector of packages?*", is that a rhetorical question or do you want an answer?

Comment: The first instance of `require` above is lacking an argument.

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas @ IRTFM could you make a solution to this problem?

Comment: I chose to answer the implicit question about why that code failed. I am advised by the Meta posting on multipart questions that I should have voted to close https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things because of the three parts but thought just focusing on the code would be the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There <strike>are</strike> were at least 3 errors in that `for` loop. First, a missing argument to the first `require`,

... then failing to set the `character.only` argument for `require`to TRUE so that `i` can get evaluated rather than taken as a package name,   (see `?require` Arguments section)

... and finally, failing to join the desired character values in the `print` calls with `paste`. (See `?print.default`'s Argument section. The print function only prints its first argument. Its second argument is the number of digits, as stated by the console error message.)

```
pkg <- c("stringr", "openxlsx")

for (i in pkg){
    print(i)
    if(require(i, character.only=TRUE)){
        print(paste(i, "is loaded correctly"))
    } else{
        print(paste("trying to install", i))
        install.packages(i)
        if(require(i, character.only=TRUE)){
            print(paste(i, "installed and loaded"))
        } else{
            stop(paste("could not install", i))
        }
    }
}
```

I did get :  "Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
there is no package called ‘openxlsx’" after the first run of that loop which I do not understand (since the message `[1] "openxlsx installed and loaded"` was printed, and the package did get installed and could be loaded. I'm guessing it had something to do with these activities being done within a function and there was some mismatch of environments??? When I removed pkg:openxlsx and re-ran my code I do not get the warning message.

Comment: @ IRTFM, thank you for your help. Totally forgot the paste, require(i) was in my original code. Ran ?require(). In the man, didnt see: character.only=TRUE. So thanks again for your valuable help!